# Check box not checked in yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

I am using yii2, i want to checked my check box,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'is_email_alerts')->checkbox(['label'=>'','checked'=>true,'uncheck'=>'0','value'=>'1']); ?>
```

But its not working

Comment: hey, i have same problem please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not the checkbox is checked is determined solely by the value of the attribute.

From the API page for [ActiveField::checkbox()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activefield.html#checkbox%28%29-detail)

> This method will generate the "checked" tag attribute according to the model attribute value

Thus just add

```
$model->is_email_alerts = true;
```

in your controller or anywhere before this call in your view.

---

Just to verify that this is the actual case: from the source for [BaseHtml::activeCheckbox()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1391)

```
public static function activeCheckbox($model, $attribute, $options = [])
{
    ...
    $value = static::getAttributeValue($model, $attribute);
    ...
    $checked = "$value" === "{$options['value']}";
    ...
    return static::checkbox($name, $checked, $options);
}
```

And the only line in [ActiveField::checkbox()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L690) where `checked` is set is

```
public static function checkbox($name, $checked = false, $options = [])
{
    $options['checked'] = (bool) $checked;
```